# html font/vector graphics question

Tags: html, rendering, vector-graphics

what's the best way to present a vector/font in html?

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) develops and recommends the [Scalable Vector Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) standard for vector graphics. All major modern web browsers support and render SVG markup directly, except Internet Explorer unfortunately. However, IE 9 will support and render SVG directly. All version of IE from v5 onwards support the [Vector Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) instead. While Microsoft continues to document VML, development of the format ceased in 1998.

You may be interested in checking out the following basic SVG examples:

- [SVG Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_examples.asp)
- [SVG Basic Tutorials: Text - Plain or Not-So-Plain](http://www.svgbasics.com/text2.html)

Comment: how is it different from HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: @Talima: VML and SVG are both vector-based, while canvas is a bitmapped system. You could still do vectors on canvas, but it's a lower level API. You may be interested in checking out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568136/svg-vs-canvas-where-is-the-web-world-going-towards) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650415/html5-canvas-element-and-svg).

Comment: @Talima: [This](http://people.mozilla.com/~vladimir/xtech2006/) is also interesting on the topic of SVG vs Canvas.

Comment: thanks. I want to use Canvas to display/draw a text document, can the fonts be drawn using svg? or would that be too slow?

Answer (score 0):

The best of using custom font in website is CSS3. Example:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'GoodFootRegular';
src: url('goodfoot.eot');
src: local('Good Foot'), local('GoodFoot'), url('goodfoot.woff') format('woff'), url('goodfoot.ttf') format('truetype');}
.classname{ font:21px bold normal GoodFootRegular;}
```